# Cross Layer Filtering vs Layer Groups using GeoServer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs, filter

To pull features using WFS from several layers in one request, I have two options: One, create a layer group, and then get features from the layer group, as opposed to individual layers. Two, use cross layer filtering to obtain features for each desired layer.

I'm not adept at cross layer filtering but it appears to me as the more flexible and robust solution. What I wish to achieve is obtain points within a selected administrative boundary. The administrative boundaries and the points/population layers are separate.

My environment: GeoServer 2.1.3, OpenLayers 2.11, PostGIS 1.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is not an option, layer groups exist only for WMS.
Cross layer filtering is to filter layers, not to get multiple ones in one request. 
If you need data from more than one layer in WFS just create a Query element for each one of them in the request, as mandated by the WFS spec, or if you are using a GET request use a comma separate value.

A quick read of the WFS specification would certainly help